# Process.Start StandardOutput always empty

Tags: c#

I tried lot's of samples posted here and elsewhere that should capture and output the StandardOutput of a process.start command. But no matter if synchronous or asynchronous the output is always empty.

```
StringBuilder outputBuilder;
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo;
Process process;

outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.Arguments = "-ss 00:00:50 -t 240 -i Input.MOV -to 00:00:02 -qscale 0 _OUTPUT.MOV";
processStartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";

process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
// enable raising events because Process does not raise events by default
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
// attach the event handler for OutputDataReceived before starting the process
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
(
    delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // append the new data to the data already read-in
        outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
    }
);
// start the process
// then begin asynchronously reading the output
// then wait for the process to exit
// then cancel asynchronously reading the output
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
process.CancelOutputRead();

// use the output
string output = outputBuilder.ToString();
```

Process is executed just as intended but there is not output captured nevertheless it's shown in the VS IDE output pane.

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Best Regards.

Comment: Also listen for errors with `BeginErrorReadLine` and the equivalent handler.

Comment: `delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)`  This looks wrong.  Just remove that and the opening/closing braces that go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amy, it's correct, the normal output is returned by

```
BeginErrorReadLine
```